# ¿Por qué $variable no produce el resultado completo?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu-server

Estoy haciendo un script para que me automatice la creacion de los usuarios en un samba-ad-dc, resulta que quiero que el usuario como login utilice su nombre y apellido ej 'Nombre Apellido', entonces cuando utilizo el siguiente comando, me lo permite:

```
samba-tool user create 'Nombre Apellido' P4ssw0rd* --given-name=nombre --surname=apellido
```

Pero la cosa está en que lo estoy haciendo en un script y he usado el siguiente código para automatizarlo que es leyendo desde un archivo .txt

```
while IFS=, read -r user nombre apellido
do
  samba-tool user create $user P4ssw0rd* --given-name=$nombre --surname=$apellido --login-shell=/bin/bash
done < nombres.txt
```

Aquí un ejemplo del archivo nombres.txt

```
'Nombre1 Apellido1',Nombre1,Apellido1
'Nombre2 Apellido2',Nombre2,Apellido2
```

Resulta que cuando ejecuto el script, solo me lee Nombre1 como user y no 'Nombre1 Apellido1' como resultado de esto cuando ejecuto el comando **samba-tool user list** sale:

```
'Nombre1
```

Y he intentado tanto poner `'Nombre1\ Apellido1'`, `nombres="'$nombre $apellido'"`...

¿Alguna idea? La verdad es que podría solo poner "Nombre1_Apellido1" pero necesito saber si hay la opción de hacer lo que he planteado en un script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que `$var` a secas en muchos casos no es suficiente y debes decir `"$var"` para que su contenido sea un todo. Esto es especialmente relevante cuando la variable contiene espacios u otros caracteres no alfanuméricos.

---

Por tanto, necesitas poner comillas dobles a tu expresión:

```
while IFS=, read -r user nombre apellido
do
  samba-tool user create "$user" P4ssw0rd* ...
#                        ^^^^^^^
done < nombres.txt
```

O bien `samba-tool user create "$nombre $apellido" ...`

---

Cuando explicas tu comando indicas que es así:

```
samba-tool user create 'Nombre Apellido' P4ssw0rd* ...
#                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Esto es, `create` recibe un parámetro entre comillas, pues si fuera sin ellas quedaría en:

```
samba-tool user create Nombre Apellido P4ssw0rd* ...
#                      ^^^^^^
```

es decir, `samba-tool` entendería que el `create` es solo para `Nombre` y que `Apellido` ya es el comando contraseña.

Para replicar este uso en Bash debes utilizar comilla doble, de manera que el parámetro que lees del archivo y que está en `$user` se pase entero a `create`. Las comillas simples no sirven en este caso pues estarían imprimiendo el literal `$user`:

```
$ user=fedor
$ echo '$user'
$user
$ echo "$user"
fedor
```

Comment: Juraría que había probado esto... , así que lo probé y funcionó gracias!